# 'input' is an invalid keyword argument for print()

Tags: python, django, graphene-python

I am using graphene-django for an api. I am trying to create a mutation for creating a brand which has foreign key of company. When i mutate, I get the following error "'input' is an invalid keyword argument for print()". I could not figure out, why this error is thrown.

Here is my mutation

```
class BrandInput(graphene.InputObjectType):

    company = graphene.List(CompanyInput)
    name = graphene.String()
    website = graphene.String()
    description = graphene.String()
    country = graphene.String()
    city = graphene.String()
    address = graphene.String()


    class CreateBrand(graphene.Mutation):

        class Arguments:

            input = BrandInput(description="These fields are required", required=True)


        class Meta:

            description = "Create Brand Mutation"

        errors = graphene.String()
        brand = graphene.Field(BrandNode)

        @staticmethod
        def mutate(root, info, **args):
            print('args', args, **args)
            if not info.context.user.is_authenticated:
                return CreateBrand(errors=json.dumps('Please Login to list your brand'))
            try:
                company = models.Company.objects.get(slug=args.get('input')['company'])
                if company:
                    brand = models.Brand.objects.create(
                        company=company,
                        name=args.get('input')['name'],
                        slug = args.get('input')['slug'],
                        website = args.get('input')['website'],
                        description = args.get('input')['description'],
                        country = args.get('input')['country'],
                        city = args.get('input')['city'],
                        address = args.get('input')['address'],
                    )
                    return CreateBrand(brand=brand, errors=null)
            except models.Company.DoesNotExist:
                return CreateBrand(errors=json.dumps('Company should be required'))
```

I felt doubt in `company = graphene.List(CompanyInput)` so i changed it to `company = graphene.String()` and provided the slug of the company so i can find the company instance when mutating the brand. But i get the same error.

The query for mutation was

```
mutation {
  createBrand(input: {company: "wafty-company", name: "Wafty Brand", website: "www.wafty.com", description: "Wafty brand description", country: "Nepal", city: "Kathmandu", address: "Baneshwor", pinCode: "44600", operationDate: "2018-10-02 15:32:37", franchisingDate: "2018-10-02 15:32:37", numberOfFranchises: "0-10", numberOfOutlets: "0-10"}) {
    errors
    brand {
      name
      slug
      website
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing keyword arguments to `print`?

Comment: That `print('args', args, **args)` call doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry it's a side effect to two programming language. In javascript we can but not in python.

Answer (score 6):

When you trying to pass arguments like this `**args` to `print()` this arguments will be unpacked as keyword arguments, and this will raise the error, since `print()` doesn't expect such arguments as `mutate()` method has. So you need to remove `**args`:

```
print('args', args)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve with the

```
print('args', args, **args)
```

line. But, anyways the python's `print` function has a syntax of ([ref](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp)):

```
print(object(s), separator=separator, end=end, file=file, flush=flush)
```

and given the `**<variableName>` will confuse the function, hence spiting the error out. If you have a dictionary of `kwargs` and you want to print the values, you may use the syntax of `*kwargs.values()`. For example:

```py
args = [1, 2]
kwargs = {'a':3, 'b':4}

print(*args, *kwargs.values())
```

will print

> 1 2 3 4

and other combinations are:

```py
print(kwargs)           # --> {'a': 3, 'b': 4}
print(*kwargs)          # --> a f
print(kwargs.values())  # --> dict_values([3, 4])
print(*kwargs.values()) # --> 3 4
```

the more relevant discussion here in [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/fa3e34/passing_listtuple_with_or_without_astrix_what_is/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).